# Calculate working hours in Excel based on in out times

Tags: excel, select

I would like to automatically calculate the working times of my employees based on the time they entered and left the company.
I have a badge system on the door that exports HTML files for every employee based on badge code.
So I figured out on how to automatically import all the tables from the html files into Excel so they can be processed more easily.

My main problem is that in and out are in the same column in the Excel file.
in following format :

Date              Hour           Action
04-01-2018        07:15          IN

04-01-2018        16:05          OUT

05-01-2018        6:52           IN

05-01-2018        16:05          OUT

Sometimes they also go out during lunch break and then I have situations like this:

06-01-2018        07:13          IN

06-01-2018        12:05          OUT

06-01-2018        12:27          IN

06-01-2018        16:06          OUT

Since in and out is in the same column I can't just do 16:06 - 07:13 so I would like to find a way to look at the dates in the first column, if the date is the same then look at the third column and select the OUT with the latest time and retract that from the IN with the earliest time.

If anyone could help me with that, that would be great.

Comment: So is the correct answer in the second case 8:53 (total hours) or 8:31 (total hours minus lunch break) ?

Comment: I assume you have a fourth column that has the employee ID/Name. Do your employees stay past midnight? If not, you can do this easily with a pivot table.

Comment: The lunch break should be deducted from the total working time. That's why I would like the earliest in thine and the latest out time and then I can just deduct 30 minutes from it.  There is a night shift at well but only a small team. I would like to focus first on the people of morning/afternoon since that's 95% of employees

Answer (score 0):

Two answers

(1) If you want the time minus the lunch break, mathematically it's

```
out1 - in1 + out2 - in2 +...
```

which can be re-arranged to give

```
out1 + out2 + ... - (in1 + in2 + ...)
```

So you can do it with a couple of SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,A1,C1:C10,"out")-SUMIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,A1,C1:C10,"in")
```

(2) If you want the time from first arriving to going home, you can get it by

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B1:B10/((A1:A10=A1)*(C1:C10="out")),1)-
AGGREGATE(15,6,B1:B10/((A1:A10=A1)*(C1:C10="in")),1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working well for the day shifts. I never heard about the aggregate function. i'll remember this one